# Finding limit of function

Tags: limits, functions

Find the following limit :
$$ \lim_{t \to(\pi/2)^-} \log\left(\frac{2 t}{\pi}\right) \log(\cos(t))$$
The indeterminate form is $0 \times\infty$
$$ \lim_{t \to(\pi/2)^-} \frac{ \log(\cos(t))}{\frac{1}{\log(\frac{2 t}{\pi})}}$$
And now it is in form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, but l'Hospital's rule doesn't help me.
Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me. What is $x \to\pi/2-0$?

Comment: $x \to \pi/2 - $

Comment: What does $x$ have to do with $t$?

Comment: IMHO is better $t \to(\pi/2)^-$ or $t \to \left(\frac{\pi}2\right)^{-}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

Set $u=\frac\pi2-t$ and rewrite the function:
$$\log\Bigl(\frac{2 t}{\pi}\Bigr)\log(\cos t)=\log\Bigl(1-\frac{2 u}{\pi}\Bigr)\log(\sin u).$$
Now, near $0$, we have
$$\log\Bigl(1-\frac{2 u}{\pi}\Bigr)\sim-\frac{2 u}{\pi}, \qquad \sin u\sim u\quad\text{hence }\;\log(\sin u)\sim\log u,$$
so that $$\log\Bigl(1-\frac{2 u}{\pi}\Bigr)\log(\sin u)\sim_0 -\frac 2\pi u\log u.$$
Can you conclude now?

Comment: For my humble opinion the answer is OK! :-)